# UIAlertController change other UIView

Tags: ios, swift, uialertcontroller

i spend lot of time but i can not figure out how can fix this problem  . I made a picker view that is appearing from bottom . it is working fine but problem is when any other event shown  alert view . same time  picker view come from top .

note . before alert view appear . picker view working fine . after alert view appear then piker view come to the top .

[image: here before alert]

bottom appear piker view code :

```
extension RegistrationController {


    func showSettings(selecteIndex : Int) {
        //show menu

        if let window = UIApplication.shared.keyWindow {

            blackView.backgroundColor = UIColor(white: 0, alpha: 0.5)

            blackView.addGestureRecognizer(UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(handleDismiss)))

            window.addSubview(blackView)

            window.addSubview(bottomView)

            bottomView.addSubview(titlebottomView)

            titlebottomView.addSubview(bottomViewActionLabel)
            titlebottomView.addSubview(doneButton)

            let height: CGFloat = 150
            let y = window.frame.height - height

            bottomView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: window.frame.height, width: window.frame.width, height: height)

            titlebottomView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: window.frame.width, height: 40)

                bottomView.addSubview(pikerViewForGender)

                bottomViewActionLabel.text = "Select your Gender"

                bottomView.addSubview(pikerViewForGender)
                pikerViewForGender.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 44, width: bottomView.frame.width, height: bottomView.frame.height - 40)

            self.bottomViewActionLabel.frame = CGRect(x: 13, y: 0, width: 150, height: 40)
            self.doneButton.frame = CGRect(x: window.frame.width - 80 , y: 0, width: 80, height: 40)

            blackView.frame = window.frame
            blackView.alpha = 0

            UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5, delay: 0, usingSpringWithDamping: 1, initialSpringVelocity: 1, options: .curveEaseOut, animations: {

                self.blackView.alpha = 1

                self.bottomView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: y, width: window.frame.width, height: height)


            }, completion: nil)
        }
    }

    func handleDismiss() {


        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5, delay: 0, usingSpringWithDamping: 1, initialSpringVelocity: 1, options: .curveEaseOut, animations: {

            self.blackView.alpha = 0

            if let window = UIApplication.shared.keyWindow {
                self.bottomView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: window.frame.height, width: window.frame.width, height: window.frame.height)


            }

        }) { (completed: Bool) in

            print("good way ....")

        }
    }

}
```

[image: when showing alert]

alert view code :

```
extension UIViewController {

   func showAlert(message: String ){

        let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Whoops", message: message, preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.alert)
        alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: UIAlertActionStyle.default, handler: {(_ action: UIAlertAction) -> Void in

            alert.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)

        }))
        self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

Comment: well... the concept is wrong from the point when you try to add subviews to a `UIWindow` instance; that is something which you need to revise entirely and not commit anymore, because the `UIAlertController` is totally fine, you are messing around with the improper implementation of the view-layer, I'm afraid.

Comment: @holex thanks you so much i don't mind . if you give answer than it will really help for my life . i am new to swift .

Answer (score 0):

Your done button is added as subview onto `titlebottomView`. When you see your done button up there, it means that your `titlebottomView` is still on your screen, not getting dismissed or brought back. So in your `handleDismiss()` function, use your desired way to make sure `titlebottomView` is in some off screen location or bring it back as best practice.

Comment: @cristainlika3 Are you triggering your alert view when user click on the done button? Can you please post that line of code? I was originally confuse by your wording of "it is working fine but alert view showing picker view come from top". I just realized that your done button is on the left top corner.

Comment: thanks . before alert view appear . picker view working fine . after alert view appear then piker view come to the top .  . and i updated my question

Comment: why you down vote me ? just because  i unable to accept your answer . trust me . i did you not found any useful your answer yet .

Comment: @cristainlika3 man I am looking into your question but if you can somehow find a log, I did not down vote you....

Comment: @cristainlika3 Updated my answer

Answer (score 0):

You custom `PickerView` will always be on top of any other presented views because you are adding `PickerView` as a subview on `MainWindow` while you're presenting `UIAlertController` on current `UIViewController`.

Add your `PickerView` as a subview of current `UIViewController` instead of `MainWindow`, that will solve the problem.

If you would have used (now deprecated) `UIAlertView`, this problem wouldn't have occurred. But unfortunately `UIAlertView` is now deprecated.

And by the way, adding `PickerView` on `MainWindow` isn't a very good approach so avoid it in future.

Hope it helps!